# Convert a regulation expression to DFA

Tags: regex, expression, computation-theory, dfa, nfa

I have been trying different ways to solve this problem for over an hour and am getting very frustrated.

The problem is: Give regular expressions and DFAs for each of the following languages over Sigma = {0,1}.

a). **{w ∈ Σ* | w contains an even number of 0s or an odd number of 1s}**

If anyone could provide hints or get me started on figuring this one out, it would be very appreciated!

I know it is something along the lines of this DFA but this one is for

**{w ∈ Σ* | w contains an even number of 0s or exactly two 1's}**

so it's a bit different but I can't figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Edited OP with picture of what I've gotten close to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it as follows: you always have to remember two things:

1. whether the number of **0**s is *even* or *odd*; and
2. whether the number of **1**s is *even* or *odd*.

Now if we denote *even* with *e* and *odd* with *o*, we consider four states: *ee* (both even), *eo* (even number of 0s and odd number of 1s), *oe* and *oo*.

Now when we read a zero (0), we simply swap the first state token, so it means we introduce transitions from:

1. *ee* - 0 -> *oe*;
2. *eo* - 0 -> *oo*;
3. *oe* - 0 -> *ee*; and
4. *oo* - 0 -> *eo*.

The same for ones (1):

1. *ee* - 1 -> *eo*;
2. *eo* - 1 -> *ee*;
3. *oe* - 1 -> *oo*; and
4. *oo* - 1 -> *oe*.

Now we only need to determine the *initial state* and the *accepting state(s)*. The intial state is *ee*, since at that moment we have considered no zeros and no ones.

Furthermore the *accepting state* can by determined by the condition:

> *w* contains an even number of 0s or an odd number of 1s

So that means the accepting states are *ee*, *eo* and *oo*. A drawing of this DFA is shown below:

[image: dfa described above]

---

There exists an algorithmic way to convert a *DFA* into an equivalent *regular expression* as is stated [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions).

You can construct a regular expression by splitting the problem into two easier problems:

- a regex that checks if the number of 0s is even; and
- a regex that checks if the number of 1s is odd.

For the first, you can use the regex:

```
(1*01*0)*1*
```

Indeed: you first have a group `(1*01*0)`. This group ensures that there are two zeros, and 1s can appear everywhere in between. We allow an arbitrary number of repetitions, since the number always remains even. The regex ends with `1*` since it is still possible that there are additional ones in the string.

The second problem can be solved with the regex:

```
0*1(0*10*1)*0*
```

The solution is more or less the same. The expression between the brackets: `(0*10*1)` ensures that the ones occur evenly. By adding a `1` in front, we ensure the number of 1s is odd.

A regular expression that then solves the problem is:

```
(1*01*0)*1*|0*1(0*10*1)*0*
```

Since the "pipe" (`|`) means "or".

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you Willem for taking the time to show the DFA as well!

Answer (score 2):

Think about what possible states you can ever be in.

- A number contains either an even number of 0's or an odd number of 0's. (2 possible states)
- A number contains either an even number of 1's or an odd number of 1's. (2 possible states)

Now let's look at what combinations are accepted by your language:

1. even 0's, even 1's: **accept**
2. even 0's, odd 1's: **accept**
3. odd 0's, even 1's: **reject**
4. odd 0's, odd 1's: **accept**

As a result, your DFA will need 4 states, of which 3 are accept states and 1 is a reject state. Every state will have 2 transitions leading to a different state. Since the empty string has an even number of 0's and an even number of 1's, the first state will be the initial state.

---

For making this into a regular expression: think about how you'd match an even number of 0's, then how you'd match an odd number of 1's. The language is just the union of these two.

Alternatively, [as suggested by Willem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35675615/1321716), you can use an algorithm to convert *any* NFA to a regular expression. It has the advantage of being very general, but it's also more technical. Either way, it should lead to an equivalent regular expression.

What does a number with an even number of 0's look like? It might start with any number of 1's, but when we do find a 0 we better find another one! There can be any number of 1's in between, but we only care about the 0's. Thus, we come up with the following regular expression:

```
1*(01*01*)*
```

You should be able to apply a similar logic to match an odd number of 1's. Finally, OR the two expressions to get the requested regular expression.

Comment: Thank you very much. This clears up a lot of my confusion.

Comment: So then for an odd number of 1's it would just be: 0*(10*)* and the regular expression is just the Union of these two?

Comment: Watch out there: that regular expression will match `11`, which has an even number of 1's! Hint: start off with a regular expression matching an *even* number of 1's, then concatenate it with a regular expression to match one additional 1 (possibly with some 0's).

Comment: I am still stuck on this regular expression.

Comment: Okay, so the following regular expression will match an *even* number of 1's: `0*(10*10*)*`. Now, for an *odd* number of 1's we just need to match one additional 1 somewhere, possibly with some 0's around it: `0*10*`. Concatenate that with the first regular expression (and simplify `0*0*` to just `0*`) to get: `0*10*(10*10*)*`

Comment: Thank you. This makes more sense now.